# Stripping whitespace from pdf page

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pymupdf

What I am trying is to crop or trim the whitespaces from each page in a large pdf file
My limited knowledge I was able to crop only the peripheral whitespaces of the page using pymupdf `set_cropbox`.But its not detecting the in between whitespace. Looking for a way to visually check for text then trim the whitespaces. Not sure which way to approach this problem.

[image: what I am trying to accomplish]

Comment: See largest interior rectangle at https://github.com/OpenStitching/lir

Comment: in other words, you want to remove *blank bands* of the page? what do you think you'll need to accomplish that?

Comment: is this file a scan (image) or is it pristine text and vector graphics?

Comment: that vertical line is curving. that's indicative of a scan. I see no source given for this file, only the screenshot in the question. what information do you have?

Comment: I gave the picture in OP's question one look and dismissed any thought of trying to decipher its fine print and googling for potential sources. OP really should have linked to the source instead of screenshooting it.

Comment: https://papers.gceguide.com/O%20Levels/Mathematics%20D%20(4024)/2022/4024_s22_qp_22.pdf     this is the link of the pdf, apologies for not noticing

Answer (score 2):

One major problem with PDF is there is no white space unless added.

Here we see the page is classically not even written in visual order so the last line is after the first and thus parsing heights from the end of page would be meaningless without calculations as to what is the largest paper space without ink irrespective of text or any other contents.

[image]

I would have said we can simply run one command line to reprint a new PDF without the large areas but then again it's not as desired.

[image]

To change font space and appearance needs either address registry default font or prepend txt with RTF font name.

However we can parse the pdftotext easily enough to reduce the double line entries down to no more than 1 line gap. I leave that to your SED or Regex abilities in Python (I don't "do" Python).

[image]

Just a side note that this is one of the [best examples seen today](https://pastpapers.papacambridge.com/directories/CAIE/CAIE-pastpapers/upload/4024_s22_qp_21.pdf) of why PDF text is found out of order when printed. So text line starts with `.` jumps forward to `m` back to `8` then skips decimal to write the line body digits (luckily in order) then skips the `m` to write the super `2`

[image]